# how to use several controllers in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm looking for an example of a Sencha Touch 2 MVC application that has more than one model, view, controller. I want to see what is the recommended way of witching to a different subject in the application.

For example: Suppose I have an application to manage calls and messages. I will have some welcome screen with a welcome controller and no model, a recent calls model, view, controller, and a messages model, view, controller. My problem is with putting and removing everything I need in the main view port, without allocating elements that are not displayed.

All the examples I found use one controller to rule them all, and a viewport with cards. I was hoping for a better technique. Also from what I saw when I start the application they specify all the models and controllers of the application, but I did not see how it can be used or why it is a good design. I thought that we want to reduce allocations on the phone.

Any pointers to examples or guidelines for how to use several controllers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to go for routing and destroying items then.

```
VIEW:       Welcome -> okBtn press
CONTROLLER: Welcome -> onOkBtnPress -> call route START
            Welcome -> deactivate -> destroy Welcome VIEW

START VIEW: view items
START CONTROLLER: route index -> Add new view to Viewport.
```

Without routing you need to add the new view in the Welcome view, which usually is not preferable.

So you basically call a route onBtnTap and destroy the old view onDeactiveView.